# Is there an api to post questions without using the websites interface?

Tags: support, api

I wanted to post questions after a proper user authentication explained [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/75/verifying-and-linking-se-users-from-external-sites). Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Yes, as of version 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything special in the API that would let you do this. You could send the user directly to the ask a question page.

I fiddled with the [FireFox plugin](https://stackapps.com/questions/316/swatch-a-firefox-plugin-for-monitoring-stack-exchange-sites-for-interesting-chan) I created to see if I could add the ability to post directly to the site to add an answer to a question or a comment if someone was already logged in. If I remember correctly there is some key that is required for the POST request and it wasn't obvious how that key was generated.

Comment: Please see my answer for details.

Comment: Don't try that, we intentionally make it very difficult to programmatically post to the sites (as an anti-bot measure).  If you find a workaround, we will break it.

Answer (score 2):

I already tried this. [Complete exasperation with sending POST requests to StackOverflow - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/58444).
So it's v2.0 or nothing.